# Saving data into binary files C#

Tags: c#

How can I hide my table database file from main application. I have a window form application, it has a button to open the file dialog and I can then pick one file. Then I want my to connect to my sqlserver, then I will save the file content into some other binary file. After all, I want to hide my db file inside my main.exe application so that people can not read what it is. I don't know what to do. Can you guide me from scrach.

Comment: If nothing to feed, throw me questions, its ok, i see if i can answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is much too broad; asking people to write your program for you is generally discouraged. Once you've tried some different approaches and have specific technical questions to which there's an objective answer, feel free to ask them. Until then, I have voted to close this question.

Comment: How broad is that ? It costs too much while you get back nothing ? for example. YES, you will just get nothing, to be sure. What I said all out here and there about my program is serious. YOU MUST CARE in case you say you don't!

Comment: The nature of your question is not appropriate for this site. This has nothing to do with my (or anyone else's) desire to get something back; the fact is that the broad nature of your question means it that is unlikely to be of use to others in the future.

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean, by "costs" I mean you don't want to share your solution because you are afraid other readers might turn your ideas (precious ?) into their ideas for writing books. You are one user too; you and others may not get anything in return because I don't know a solution to offer. But if my post is not helpful, you can post replies as people below do, so many others can also find them useful too. Why don't you ? instead of voting to close ? Please stop your neat/clean/clear and beauful post making methods. It's ideas, not the make-ups, sorry I am not beautiful at all, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than merging the data file with your executable, perhaps you should consider using an embedded database that supports data encryption.

One option would be SQL Lite with the Encryption extension:
http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html

SQL Server also supports encryption:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx

Maybe you are using SQL Server Compact? This article might help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/05/14/security-and-encryption-for-sql-server-compact.aspx

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. It might be a useful suggestion at the end of an answer that does so, but on it's own should at best be a comment to the original question. (Also, it's not a good idea to say "So your Ford works, but you should switch to Toyota instead because it comes with a different navigation system". If the database is already SQL Server, and the app is written using it, a total change of DB might not be feasible.

Comment: The question was a little broad and unclear, so I was specifically responding to this bit: "I want to hide my db file inside my main.exe application so that people can not read what it is". To me it sounds like the questioner wants an embedded encrypted database, but doesn't quite know how to ask for one.  Further, I had already edited my response to include information about encryption for SQL Server before you commented. As an aside, perhaps you should try putting more energy into helping people, and less into criticising others who are trying to help and/or learn?

Comment: Mikey: Point taken. I'll try and be more helpful. As you can see, I've little or no experience helping people here. Thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps you should look at people's rep and posting history before you get rude about constructive criticism (made *without* downvoting you, BTW).

Comment: I did look at your rep, but I don't see how it gives you a license to act in the way that you did.

Comment: I made a suggestion on how to improve your post or avoid downvotes. Sorry - I was trying to help you. Next time I'll just downvote and move on.

Comment: I have been downvoted for years, I am still here.